# Persona 3 Portable - 10/21 atm, reached tartarus – What do I do?

Tags: persona-3-portable

I've reached the roof of Tartarus ('This is the end of Tartarus' or something like that) and there is nothing there aside from a teleport to the hall with your friends.

Date: 10/21 (I think this is mid-game but I'm not completely sure.)

My details:

- Player Level: 54 (HP: 383, SP: 320)
- Stats: Academics (Genius), Charm (Charismatic), Courage (Badass) – Basically maxed out.
- Main personas: Tam Lin (Lv. 44), Yamatano-orochi (Lv. 40), Fortuna (Lv. 27). (These are my main ones. Aside from these, I am trying to mix and create good ones, but so far haven't found any to my pleasing.)

S-Link:

- SEES: Rank 5
- Classmate: Rank 7
- Student council: Rank 8
- Old couple: Rank 4
- Track team: Rank 6
- Treasurer: Rank 8
- Online game: Rank 2
- Photography club: Rank 1
- Team Manager: Rank Rank 7
- Girl at the Shrine: Rank 2
- Mysterious boy: Rank 8
- Transfer Student: Rank 1
- Unusual Monk: Rank 5
- Gourmet King: Rank 4

Really not sure what to do. (And yes, I am terrible at this game).

Possible options:

- Continue leveling? To what level should I be aiming at? How much time should I be spending in Tartarus out of the 7 days in the week and from which floors should I start from (Level 150-ish?)
- -Or- Level up S-Link?
- What should I do with my money? I have 2,181,839 yen at the moment. I usually get my weapons from Tartarus, rather than buying it from the Police Store.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.  Are you stuck and can't continue?  Or are you done, and are asking us what you should do now that you've finished?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can clear each new block of Tartarus each month and don't have trouble with the full moon events, your level and equipment are (by definition) sufficient. There's no upcoming massive spike in difficulty that you need to worry about, so as long as you can keep up with the new content then you're on the right track.

You may want to try to fully max out some S.Links at this point; each S.Link gives you a bonus at rank 10 (specifically, each one unlocks the ability to fuse a certain Persona, usually a pretty good one). Unless you've been following an S.Link FAQ, it's unlikely that you'll be able to max them all out, so just go for the ones that have Personas that you're interested in, or the ones that you're already close to maxing out.

Generally, it's a good idea to try to keep your Personas up to date (as close to your level as possible) by fusing new ones as your level increases. If you can't find any appealing ones, you could refer to a fusion FAQ to figure out what some strong Personas are for your level range, or you can just wing it by fusing together high-level personas until you start to see new ones start appearing (and then you can try fusing those if you want, etc). This is also a good way to spend money if you don't need equipment, since recalling Personas from the compendium costs money.

If you want some specific recommendations for strong Personas that are around your level range:

> Surt (requires Magician S.Link MAX)
>  Kikuri-Hime
>  Thor (requires Chariot S.Link MAX)
>  Jatayu (requires level 55)
>  Byakko (requires level 57)
>  Loki (requires level 58)

Answer (score 0):

After the boss battle, Tartarus opens up again on

> 11/6.

I was confused because the other characters mentioned how they reached the end of Tartarus and how it was all going to end after the full moon battle.

Apparently not.